# Getting 1st element of a nested list, based on criteria for 2nd element

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a list such as {{abc,1},{def,2},{ghi,1},{jkl,3}}.

I would like to extract elements that have 1 as the second element (ignoring those that have 2 or 3 as their second element).

In the case above, I want a command to extract the elements: "abc" and "ghi", based on the criteria that their second elements are equalled to 1.

How should I go about doing so?

Comment: Have a look at `Cases`.

Comment: This works! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Cases[{{abc, 1}, {def, 2}, {ghi, 1}, {jkl, 3}}, {_, 1}]
```

The command above solved it.

Comment: `Select[{{abc, 1}, {def, 2}, {ghi, 1}, {jkl, 3}}, Last@# == 1 &]`